# Extract html from div and remove some divs inside html and then return result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is very simple, but I have no idea how I can store result back? So what I am doing here

```
<div id="test_div">
    <div class="wrapper1">My logo wrapper</div>
    <div class="keep">My Table</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">My Wrapper</div>
</div>
```

Now, using Javascript, with jQuery, I'll get everything like following:

```
function foo() {
    var html = document.getElementById("test_div").innerHTML;
    //now I want to remove some inner divs
    var result = $(html).remove("wrapper1");  //I know this is wrong 
    //but I would like to do something like above, so after I remove an element 
    //and its contents, the function will return a result
}
```

So, it's very simple but I don't know how I can do this: first remove a `div` element inside test_div and then return the remaining contents of test_div. Sorry I forgot to add one very important line **I don't wont to remove element from the current page as suggested solution and even using remove method will remove it from the main page So I wanted to keep as it is on the main page but remove and just get refine result to store in result var**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3trqLju4/

```
<div id="test_div">
    <div class="wrapper1">My logo wrapper</div>
    <div class="keep">My Table</div>
    <div class="wrapper2">My Wrapper</div>
</div>  
<input type="button" id="btn" value="refine"/>

$("#btn").click(function() 
{
   var copyhtml = $("#test_div").clone();
   $(copyhtml).find(".wrapper1").remove();
   alert(copyhtml.html());
});
```

Comment: Awesome bro that's what I want you are too good how you figure this out

Comment: Glad it worked for you. In the future, if you don't want anything to reflect on DOM, always copy the DOM object using clone() and then fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(html).remove(".wrapper1");
```

and

```
result = document.getElementById("test_div").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to remove wrapper1 from test_div, you could use:

```
$("#wrapper1").remove();
```

If you would like to move wrapper1 and use it later:

```
var wrapper1 = $("#wrapper1").detach();
$(wrapper1).appendTo("#some-new-div");
```

Comment: Hi thx but I update the question as what you suggest using remove will remove from current page but I don't want to remove it from current page so need to visible all the time the element and only remove when it's on javascript side to get refine result.